# Web: Restricting write access to files within current folder or sub-folders

Tags: web-applications, file-io, file-access

Working on a new project that lets users create their own small websites which each get their own folders on the root directory. However I came accross a security issue of which I'm not sure how I can fix it: right now, users can edit their website's code and use this to edit other websites codes (simply routing back one directory and selecting a different map of another website and access those files, using PHP or anything). But this obviously is not desired, and I'm not sure whether I can prevent this with some PHP codes or perhaps Htaccess codes, or whether this should be done from within the server.

What I basicly need is a restriction for files within a certain folder to not be able to access (write to / edit) files that are not in that specific folder or a sub-folder of it. Or in other words: a file in map A can only write to files within map A or within a sub-folder of map A.

Does anyone here know whether and how this could be done?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Skyfe.